# Freeze a cross origin iframe while it's refreshing with JavaScript/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have a dashboard website which has a weather widget inside an iframe that I'm trying to make auto-refresh. The issue is when the iframe is refreshed, it blinks. Is there a way to "freeze" the iframe visually using JavaScript/CSS while I'm reloading it?

Comment: You could take a screenshot, overlay that on top of the iframe, refresh the iframe, then remove the screenshot. Seems like a whole lotta whole lotta for a little blink though.

Comment: Could have two iframes for the same thing. Have one hidden. When you want to refresh, refresh the hidden one, wait for it to complete, then show it and hide the earlier one.